# class << self, alias_method, and monkey patching Mechanize::Cookie

Tags: ruby, mechanize, monkeypatching, alias-method, alias-method-chain

I have an issue with Mechanize::Cookie misbehaving and I want to trying to monkey patch it.
My code:

```
class Mechanize::Cookie
  class << self; alias_method :old_parse, :parse end
  def self.parse(uri, str, log = Mechanize.log)
    puts 'new parse!'
    #str.gsub!(/domain[^;]*;/,'')
    old_parse(uri, str, log)
  end
end
```

when I add this, the cookies don't get added and I can't figure out why.

**Edit:**
To see the problem try this code with and without the monkey patch:

```
agent = Mechanize.new
agent.get 'http://www.google.com/'
pp agent.cookie_jar
```

Without patch you will see a full cookie jar, with it an empty one.

Comment: Does "new parse!" get printed out?

Comment: Yes, "new parse!" gets printed out and I can tell that old_parse is getting called too because I put a 'puts' line there to check it. But cookies don't get saved when I include this code.

Comment: And cookies were saved when you don't include the code, right?

Comment: @Andrew that's right. I've edited my question to help show the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the original parse method has a `yield cookie if block_given?` statement in it. You'll need to be able to pass a block as well.

EDIT:

To be more clear...

```
class Foo
    def self.x
        yield "yielded from x!" if block_given?
    end
end

class Foo
    class <<self
        alias :y :x
    end
    # new implementation of x's last parameter is an optional block
    def self.x(&block) 
        puts "in redefined x."
        puts "block=#{block}"
        self.y(&block) #use the block as the last parameter 
    end
end

Foo.x{|value| puts "value is '#{value}'"}
```

Comment: Thanks z5h, I think this is the right answer. I could use another hint though if you have one.